# Chrome Extension "Refused to load the script" (Tried updating manifest)

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I know this question has been asked before but the answer I've viewed don't fix my issue.
I'm developing a Chrome extension:

I get this error:
`Refused to load the script '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".`

Here's my manifest (v3):

```
"content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
    },
```

I even tried:

```
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self';"
```

And entered the domain I was getting an error on, but then Chrome doesn't allow me to upload the extension.

[image]

Any solution?

The script I'm getting an error on is a link to my firebase relational database.
I'm not even calling this script anywhere in the code, I think it's being called when I'm trying to access my database:

```
https://xyz-310ie-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=xyxyz
```

I'm changed the script a bit above to keep it confidential.

Also note that I'm getting this error in my App.js (react file), where I'm just removing the item from my db using:

```
const itemRef = ref(db, 'items/' + itemToRemove.firebaseKey);
remove(itemRef)
```

Adding the item works fine (adding it is done in background.js of the plugin).

**And note that it doesn't happen always.**

- If I reload the plugin, I can remove the items.
- If I add a few items, and then try to remove them, it gives me that error. Even though the items are successfully added in the db.